# How do I make text and other items look like chalk without a specialized font using only HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a few items:

- Couple lines of text
- An image that is colored solid white (icon, etc.)
- Border (should look like chalk)

**I don't need it to look handwritten but I want it to look "worn" and add texture.**

I would prefer only CSS and HTML only, but I *guess* Javascript would be okay too. I already have a chalkboard-like background I made in GIMP. **Is this even possible without using 10,000,000,000 libraries or web fonts?** I don't really want to do either because of *messy* licensing.

I had an idea about creating an overlay that is textured and darker and making that transparent, but then that would show everywhere including the background, not just the content. Also, besides me not knowing the code to move the content under the image (haven't learned much HTML5 yet I have to say so there might be something there that I haven't seen), it would block any links.

---

**Examples of What I want it to look like (follow links):**
[Example 1](http://cdn3.fiverrcdn.com/photos/640029/v2_680/Chalkboardsample.jpg?1330641932), [Example 2](http://devisefunction.com/tutorials/chalkboard_wordpress_layout/Picture%2031.jpg). See how when you zoom in they have that "shaded" texture. I'm trying to figure out how to apply a "mask" over the text of a texture I draw but in CSS I can't really find any way to do this for text. I can fill the background, but not the text itself.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you define as _"looking like chalk"_.

Comment: I don't think you need 10 billion libraries... maybe only a few hundred thousand.  Seriously, make the letters as small images and compose the picture dynamically.  This is pretty much the only option other than using a (i.e. one) font.

Comment: @Jim Can you tell me if my edit clarified anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using SVG and masking, for example with textures from [Subtlepatterns](https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/).

```js
WebFontConfig = {
  google: {
    families: ['Coming+Soon::latin']
  }
};
(function() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/uploads/pool_table.png);
}

svg {
  opacity: 0.9;
  width: 7.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  font: 900 500%/1.2 'Coming Soon', cursive;
}

text {
  fill: url(#texture);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <pattern id="texture" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="400" >
        <image xlink:href="https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/uploads/so-white.png" width="400" height="400" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text y="1.2em">placeholder text</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the JS on the JSFiddle for? It seems to change the font appearance somehow... By the way I like that it's one of the only solutions that I could find without a web font. (Your example does contain one but that isn't necessary for it to work.) Didn't know that this was possible and I can create my own textures. Also, it's nice that the text still acts like normal text! +1 and accept!

Comment: The Js is for including the font, it's easiest to do it on the fiddle that way. Note that you can also use transparent png images for masking and such in SVG which will allow you to add this effect to icons _et al_ as well. [A sample implementation](http://blog.persistent.info/2013/06/image-based-svg-masking.html).

Comment: Never knew that abbreviation... *et al*.

Comment: fantastic solution. do you mind explaining the "500%/1.2" part for the font-size in the css? I have never seen it before.

Comment: 500% is font-size, 1.2 is line-height, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font

Comment: it would seem that both iamages used in the example ae not available any more. it would be nice if it would have been updated @Etheryte